# Getting a permission error while pip installing rpy2

Tags: python, pip, rpy2

I attempt to install Rpy2, running the Anaconda Powershell Prompt as administrator, yet still get this permission error.  No idea what or why this is happening.

```
(base) PS C:\Windows\system32> pip install rpy2
Collecting rpy2
  Using cached rpy2-3.5.13.tar.gz (218 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [28 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\nmagd\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\nmagd\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "C:\Users\nmagd\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "C:\Users\nmagd\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-nhr70u10\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 341, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
        File "C:\Users\nmagd\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-nhr70u10\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 323, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\nmagd\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-nhr70u10\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 338, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 124, in <module>
        File "<string>", line 110, in get_r_c_extension_status
        File "C:\Users\nmagd\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-r_oz3azd\rpy2_8862bdec747d4e23b24c9709ec7649ca\./rpy2/situation.py", line 286, in get_r_flags
          _get_r_cmd_config(r_home, flags,
        File "C:\Users\nmagd\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-r_oz3azd\rpy2_8862bdec747d4e23b24c9709ec7649ca\./rpy2/situation.py", line 246, in _get_r_cmd_config
          output = subprocess.check_output(
        File "C:\Users\nmagd\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 421, in check_output
          return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
        File "C:\Users\nmagd\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 503, in run
          with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
        File "C:\Users\nmagd\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 971, in __init__
          self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
        File "C:\Users\nmagd\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1456, in _execute_child
          hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
      PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Added --user and also ran as admin.

Comment: It seems to be trying to run R.  Have you installed R?  Have you proven you can run it by itself?  Is it possible you have a directory called "R" in your folder?

Comment: Yup installed to C:\Program Files\R\R-4.3.1.  I have run it separately.

Comment: I see you have filed an issue.  Did you set the `R_HOME` environment variable as suggested here: https://github.com/rpy2/rpy2/issues/1032 ?

Comment: Yes indeed to the same folder as above.